# Passing data from Vue Instance to local Vue Component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a single `Vue` Instance with a local Component like so

```
// vue instance for the navbar menu
var foo = new Vue({
    el: '#custom-header',
    data: {
        label1 : 'text1',
        lable2 : 'text2',
        lable3 : 'text3',
        lable4 : 'text4'
    },
    methods: {

    },
    components : {
      'container-header' : {
          template : '<div class="col">'+
                      '<div class="custom-erp-activity-details">'+
                        '<span id="custom-erp-activity">{{ lable1 }}</span>'+
                        '<span id="custom-erp-activity-name">/ {{ label2 }}</span>'+
                        '<span id="custom-erp-activity-name">/ {{ label3 }}</span>'+
                      '</div>'+
                      '<div class="custom-erp-activity-controls">'+
                        '<button class="btn btn-danger" id="custom-erp-toggle-views">'+
                          '{{ label4 }}'+
                        '</button>'+
                      '</div>'+ 
                    '</div>'
      },
      props : ['label1']
    }
  })
```

How can I use the Label1 from the parent data in component? I tried to use `props` but I am still getting errors like this for all the four labels

> Property or method "label1" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property

Comment: What errors are you getting? Don't forget that you will have to pass the value in your parent template: `<container-header :label1="label1"></container-header>`

Comment: I have added the error message in the question and yes I do pass in the element like so `<container-header :label1="label1" :label2="label2" :label3="label3" :label4="label4"></container-header> `

Comment: Oh, it looks like your `props` are not actually part of your component, You need to move them into the component.

Comment: Can you share the HTML too? The code for `#custom-header`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the props part of your component.

```
components : {
  'container-header' : {
     template : '...',
     props : ['label1'] // HERE
  },
  // props: ['label1'] NOT HERE
}
```

Note that the props are defined as a property of the `container-header` component.